# cookTriangleMesh access exception

Tags: c++, c++17, directx-11, assimp, physx

```
PxTriangleMesh* PhysX::CreateTriangleMesh(const PxVec3* verts, const PxU32 numVerts
    , const PxU32* indexs, const PxU32 numIndexes, PxPhysics* physics, PxCooking* cooking)
{
    // Create descriptor for triangle mesh
    PxTriangleMeshDesc meshDesc;
    meshDesc.points.count = numVerts;
    meshDesc.points.stride = sizeof(PxVec3);    
    meshDesc.points.data = verts;

    meshDesc.triangles.count = numIndexes / 3;
    meshDesc.triangles.stride = 3 * sizeof(PxU32);
    meshDesc.triangles.data = indexs;

    // for prevent stackoverflow
    PxU32 estimatedVertSize = numVerts * sizeof(PxVec3) * 1.5;
    PxU32 estimatedIndexSize = numIndexes * sizeof(PxU32) * 1.5;
    PxU32 initialSize = estimatedVertSize + estimatedIndexSize;
    CustomPhysXMemory writeBuffer(initialSize);

    //PxDefaultMemoryOutputStream writeBuffer;
    bool status = cooking->cookTriangleMesh(meshDesc, writeBuffer);
    if (!status)
        return nullptr; 

    PxDefaultMemoryInputData readBuffer(writeBuffer.getData(), writeBuffer.getSize());
    PxTriangleMesh* triangleMesh = physics->createTriangleMesh(readBuffer);

    return triangleMesh;
}
```

I want to give a collider to mesh that load by assimp so I made a physX triangleMesh.
In many situations, it works
But sometimes in cookTriangleMesh
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD322F259E (PhysXCooking_64.dll) in Client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000019F69AA8000.
occurs.

I was worried about the capacity of buffer and gave him a 1.5 times space, and I checked
*((physx::PxSimpleTriangleMesh*)&meshDesc),nd {points={count=82772 } triangles={count=43798 } flags={mBits=0 } }
writeBuffer.mBuffer.capacity() 2278260
These two always came out the same either success or failure..

So I don't have a clue what the problem is. Can someone who knows the problem and how to solve it help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem which is related to Assimp. I checked the Physix-API and I was wondering why you have calculated a initial size.

In this example the writebuffer was not initialided: [Physix Example](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/Geometry.html)

Maybe this would be an option for you? And I strongly recommend to use the validation methods to get more information aabout your issue:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    // mesh should be validated before cooked without the mesh cleaning
    bool res = theCooking->validateTriangleMesh(meshDesc);
    PX_ASSERT(res);
#endif

PxTriangleMesh* aTriangleMesh = theCooking->createTriangleMesh(meshDesc,
thePhysics->getPhysicsInsertionCallback());
```

Hope that helps a little bit.